# User Defined Immutable Class giving unexpected results

Tags: java, immutability

This is regarding an immutable class that I have created.
It is as follows:

```
final class ImmutableClass
{
  private final Date d;

  public ImmutableClass(Date d)
  {
     this.d=d;
  }

  public Date getD()
  {
    return this.d;
  }
```

}

When I use this above class in the below class as:

```
public class UserClass
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Date d1 = new Date();
    ImmutableClass im= new ImmutableClass(d1);
    System.out.print("Date is : " + im.getD() + ", object is " + im);//printing originals

    //trying to change the date
    d1.setMonths("10");
    System.out.print("New Date is : " + im.getD() + ",New object is " + im);//printing  latter ones
  }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Date is : Wed Dec 10 10:38:43 IST 2014, object is com.fedex.hrt.hrmailbox.ImmutableClass@19616c7

New Date is : Mon Feb 10 10:38:43 IST 2014,New object is com.fedex.hrt.hrmailbox.ImmutableClass@19616c7
```

The date object in ImmutableClass gets changed and even the object is same , no new object is created.

This is against the definition of Immutable Classes. 
Kindly suggest whether I am wrong in my approach or did I missed out something regarding concept of immutability ??

Regards !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caller still has a reference to the `Date` (and can modify their reference). You can prevent that if you `clone()` it in the constructor. Like,

```
public ImmutableClass(Date d)
{
  this.d = (Date) d.clone();
}
```

Also, a caller could modify the `Date` you return in `getD` so you should clone() there as well;

```
public Date getD()
{
  return this.d != null ? (Date) this.d.clone() : null;
}
```

Alternatively, for a `Date`, store the number of milliseconds it wraps like

```
final class ImmutableClass {
    private final long d;

    public ImmutableClass(Date d) {
        this.d = (d != null) ? d.getTime() : 0;
    }

    public Date getD() {
        return new Date(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is happening only in case of Date object, in other cases like String(class),  int(primitive)...it returns the original values while calling getXXX() even if we change the reference variable d....why is the behaviour different?

Comment: @sukhparmar It happens because of object references (and passing references by value still passes the reference). String is immutable. As are primitive and wrapper types.

Comment: now I got it, coz Date class is mutable..so special care is to be taken while returning it as u said to create new instance..thanks Elliot a lot